# Reputable alternatives to The Conversation for science communication?

Tags: communication, science, science-communication

What are some popular press alternatives to [The Conversation](https://theconversation.com/us) that are perhaps more reputable than [Medium](https://medium.com/) or HuffPost that accept pitches from academics communicating their research for a general audience?